# How to pass HttpServletRequest using RestTemplate (POST)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

i am trying to call service B from service A

Service A:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { ""getCustomer"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> webApiQueryByPost(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    Map<String, String[]> email = request.getParameterMap();
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();

    Object response = rest.postForObject("http://localhost:8084/getCustomer", request, Object.class, email);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

Service B:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "getCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> getWebCustomer(@RequestParam String email,
        HttpServletRequest request) {   
        return webCustomerDataService.getCustomerData(email);
}
```

Service A needs to pass the request to Service B.

Exception :

> ```
> > org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
> > Could not write content: not in non blocking mode. (through reference
> > chain:
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["inputStream"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream["ready"]);
> > nested exception is
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: not in non
> > blocking mode. (through reference chain:
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["inputStream"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream["ready"])
> >     at
> > org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:774)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:567)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:538)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:340)
> >     at
> > com.xx.yy.zz.controller.MainController.webApiQueryByPost(MainController.java:78)
> >     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> > sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >     at
> > sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
> > org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
> >     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
> >     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > com.xx.xx.xx.filter.BlueBerryCORSFilter.doFilter(BlueBerryCORSFilter.java:54)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
> >     at
> > org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
> >     at
> > org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
> >     at
> > org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
> >     at
> > org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
> >     at
> > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> >     at
> > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> >     at
> > org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> >     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: not in non
> > blocking mode. (through reference chain:
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["inputStream"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream["ready"])
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:187)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:647)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:128)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1902)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
> >     ... 54 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: not in non
> > blocking mode.  at
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.isReady(InputBuffer.java:285)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.isReady(CoyoteInputStream.java:242)
> >     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> > sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >     at
> > sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:466)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
> >     ... 61 more
> > org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
> > Could not write content: not in non blocking mode. (through reference
> > chain:
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["inputStream"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream["ready"]);
> > nested exception is
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: not in non
> > blocking mode. (through reference chain:
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["inputStream"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream["ready"])
> >     at
> > org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:774)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:567)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:538)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:340)
> >     at
> > com.xx.yy.zz.controller.MainController.webApiQueryByPost(MainController.java:78)
> >     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> > sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >     at
> > sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
> > org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
> >     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
> >     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > com.xx.yy.zz.filter.BlueBerryCORSFilter.doFilter(BlueBerryCORSFilter.java:54)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
> >     at
> > org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
> >     at
> > org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
> >     at
> > org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
> >     at
> > org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
> >     at
> > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> >     at
> > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> >     at
> > org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> >     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: not in non
> > blocking mode. (through reference chain:
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["inputStream"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream["ready"])
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:187)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:647)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:128)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1902)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
> >     ... 54 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: not in non
> > blocking mode.  at
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.isReady(InputBuffer.java:285)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.isReady(CoyoteInputStream.java:242)
> >     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> > sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >     at
> > sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:466)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
> >     ... 61 more
> > org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
> > Could not write content: not in non blocking mode. (through reference
> > chain:
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["inputStream"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream["ready"]);
> > nested exception is
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: not in non
> > blocking mode. (through reference chain:
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["inputStream"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream["ready"])
> >     at
> > org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:208)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:774)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:567)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:538)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:340)
> >     at
> > com.xx.yy.zz.controller.MainController.webApiQueryByPost(MainController.java:78)
> >     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> > sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >     at
> > sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
> > org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
> >     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at
> > org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
> >     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > com.xx.yy.gateway.filter.BlueBerryCORSFilter.doFilter(BlueBerryCORSFilter.java:54)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
> >     at
> > org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
> >     at
> > org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
> >     at
> > org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
> >     at
> > org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
> >     at
> > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> >     at
> > java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> >     at
> > org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> >     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: not in non
> > blocking mode. (through reference chain:
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade["inputStream"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream["ready"])
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:210)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:177)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer.wrapAndThrow(StdSerializer.java:187)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:647)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:505)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:128)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1902)
> >     at
> > org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:231)
> >     ... 54 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: not in non
> > blocking mode.  at
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.isReady(InputBuffer.java:285)
> >     at
> > org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.isReady(CoyoteInputStream.java:242)
> >     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> > sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >     at
> > sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:466)
> >     at
> > com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:639)
> >     ... 61 more
> ```

Motive of passing the whole Request is to make this method generic for different requests and it should only pass the request from Service A to Service B .

Do we need to convert the request into Map(to extract request param's from HttpServletRequest)?

Is there any way to pass the HttpServletRequest directly to Service B ?

Please note: i tried different methods available in RestTemplate.

Any help / Pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why you are sending request?? if you don't send also you can have request param in rest controller

Comment: @Sam : i wanted to make this method generic for all the Requests and not only "/getCustomer" and different number of  Request params are used in different requests. So i thought Service A will just deliver the whole Request to Service B and Service B will handle the logic.

Comment: this is enough => Object response = rest.postForObject("http://localhost:8084/getCustomer", Object.class, email);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response,HttpStatus.OK);

Comment: Even though you wont send the request rest will take the particular request sent from particular url(which is request) so no need to send request through postForObject

Comment: if it works for you let me know..i will post the answer

Comment: it gives me 400 Bad Request, may be because of number of Request parameters in Service B are more ?

Comment: Why dont you perform a `request.getParameterMap()` and send it for rest template call instead of sending the whole `request` itself ?

Comment: add / to url @RequestMapping(value = "/getCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)

Comment: it is there: @RequestMapping(value = "getCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<Object> getWebCustomer(@RequestParam String email,
   HttpServletRequest request) { .....

Comment: Is there an answer to this? I have a situation where I want to get request from client & send it as is to another server. My API acts as a bridge. Is there a way where we can accept request & make the same request to another server in spring boot?